# Magento Payment Gateways Not Working

Tags: magento, authorize.net

Magento v 1.9.1.0
Trying to use Authorize.net and/or Paypal. Neither are working... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Authorize gives an error that says "There was an error processing your order. Please contact us or try again later." Exception log follows:

> 2015-03-20T23:53:05+00:00 ERR (3):  exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout
>   exceeded; try restarting transaction' in
>   /..../public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /..../public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
>
> ## 1 /..../public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
>
> ## 2 /..../public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
>
> ## 3 /..../public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
>
> ## 4 /..../public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `si`.*, ...', Array)
>
> ## 5 /..../public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `si`.*, ...', Array)
>
> ## 6 /..../public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
>
> ## 7 /..../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Resource/Stock.php(138):
>
> Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
>
> ## 8 /..../public_html/app/code/local/Mana/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock.php(50):
>
> Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Resource_Stock->getProductsStock(Object(Mana_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock),
>   Array, true)
>
> ## 9 /..../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Observer.php(635):
>
> Mana_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock->registerProductsSale(Array)
>
> ## 10 /..../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer->subtractQuoteInventory(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
>
> ## 11 /..../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer),
>
> 'subtractQuoteIn...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
>
> ## 12 /..../public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('sales_model_ser...', Array)
>
> ## 13 /..../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(187):
>
> Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_model_ser...', Array)
>
> ## 14 /..../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249):
>
> Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
>
> ## 15 /..../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(784):
>
> Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
>
> ## 16 /..../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(579):
>
> Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
>
> ## 17 /..../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418):
>
> Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
>
> ## 18 /..../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250):
>
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
>
> ## 19 /..../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172):
>
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>
> ## 20 /..../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>
> ## 21 /..../public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>
> ## 22 /..../public_html/index.php(91): Mage::run('', 'store')
>
> ## 23 {main}
>
> Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try
>   restarting transaction, query was: SELECT `si`.*, `p`.`type_id` FROM
>   `magentocataloginventory_stock_item` AS `si`  INNER JOIN
>   `magentocatalog_product_entity` AS `p` ON p.entity_id=si.product_id
>   WHERE (stock_id=1) AND (product_id IN(1661396)) FOR UPDATE' in
>   /..../public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /..../public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
>
> ## 1 /..../public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
>
> ## 2 /..../public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
>
> ## 3 /..../public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `si`.*, ...', Array)
>
> ## 4 /..../public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `si`.*, ...', Array)
>
> ## 5 /..../public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
>
> ## 6 /..../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Resource/Stock.php(138):
>
> Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
>
> ## 7 /..../public_html/app/code/local/Mana/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock.php(50):
>
> Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Resource_Stock->getProductsStock(Object(Mana_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock),
>   Array, true)
>
> ## 8 /..../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Observer.php(635):
>
> Mana_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock->registerProductsSale(Array)
>
> ## 9 /..../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer->subtractQuoteInventory(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
>
> ## 10 /..../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer),
>
> 'subtractQuoteIn...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
>
> ## 11 /..../public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('sales_model_ser...', Array)
>
> ## 12 /..../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(187):
>
> Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_model_ser...', Array)
>
> ## 13 /..../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249):
>
> Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
>
> ## 14 /..../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(784):
>
> Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
>
> ## 15 /..../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(579):
>
> Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
>
> ## 16 /..../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418):
>
> Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
>
> ## 17 /..../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250):
>
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
>
> ## 18 /..../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172):
>
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>
> ## 19 /..../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>
> ## 20 /..../public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>
> ## 21 /..../public_html/index.php(91): Mage::run('', 'store')
>
> ## 22 {main}

Answer (score 0):

you need to refresh cache, cache storage and reindex from backend then check it.

Comment: It was the re-index that was blocking the transactions. As soon it was complete, the exact same configurations let the transaction go through.

Answer (score 0):

For authorized.net, if you are using testing account then in magneto,
system > Configuration > Payment methods > Authorize.net section
set following details:

Enable : yes
Api Login Id: this you will get from authorize.net account
Api Key: this you will get from authorize.net account
New Order Status: Processing
Test Mode: No
Gateway URL: https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll

Using this configuration, you will be able to finish sandbox transaction.